# Validating dates in aspnet mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have my ViewModel on which I've defined my properties; one of them is a DateTime field defined as:

```
    [DisplayName("Data")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Selezionare una data")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,  DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" )]
    public DateTime? DtNews { get;set; }
```

When I submit the form I always receive the error msg "The value '13/07/2011' is not valid for DtNews" because the system swaps days and months ... I need to have dd/mm/yyyy format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the culture in your web.config to some culture for which the date format is `dd/MM/yyyy`. For example that's the case with `it-IT`:

```
<globalization culture="it-IT" uiCulture="it-IT"/>
```

By default the culture is set to `auto`. This means that ASP.NET uses the browser settings in order to deduce the culture of the client. So if the browser is configured to use `en-US`, then the format for dates will be `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Another possibility is to set the format for the current thread culture:

```
var dtfi = (DateTimeFormatInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.Clone();
dtfi.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy";
dtfi.DateSeparator = "/";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat = dtfi;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat = dtfi;
```

Comment: globalization doesn't work for me. The second variant throws exception like "property is read-only" for last 2 statements if I put it into global.asax BeginRequest